# fatal error reading xml file (I have done calculations with quantum espresso in version 7.1

Tags: crash

I have done calculations with quantum espresso  in version 7.1
and there are  problems in calculating scf, nscf, bands, or dos.
when I use version 7.1 there is an error like this:

> %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
> task #         0
> from read_conf_from_file : error #         1
> fatal error reading xml file
> %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

I think this is a bug and I try to use the latest version, which is
version 6.5 and do the scf, kpoint, and bandstructure calculations,
but when I count nscf, there is the same CRASH as version 7.1.  how is the solution?

Comment: who made the xml file? and can we see the contents? I would assume the xml is faulty :)

Comment: task #         1
     from read_conf_from_file : error #         1
     fatal error reading xml file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is typically associated with the input file (.in). Check variable names, double spaces, and/or misplaced values. Don't forget to separate name lists using /. The output data can hint at the error, so you should check it. Finally, be sure that your input files point to the same outdir, and that you have performed an scf calculation beforehand. If further questions arise, feel free to ask.